# No lease exception

Tags: multithreading, pyspark, hana

I am trying to import 300M dataset from SAP HANA table into hive using pyspark code, used multiprocessing ,10 threads got no lease exception

```
Exception in thread "main" 19/02/27 11:20:32 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close inode 1499015670 org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /user/ck/.sparkStaging/application_1551278166756_0297/abc.keytab (inode 1499015670): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1650244877_1 does not have any open files. at
```

Comment: is says "File does not exist"